# What is supposed to happen when you install Gmail webapp?

Tags: 14.04, webapps, gmail

I have installed Gmail (and other Google as well) webapps into Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit. After that I rebooted the system hoping that webapps will integrate into the system.

But after logging back to the system, I see no changes. If I click on email envelope (top bar), I don't see my inbox. Also if I try to search email in Dash via `gmail keyword`, nothing happens as well.

Am I using this wrongly or webapps don't work? What was supposed to happen when I install webapps?

Note: I did start the Gmail app from Dash and logged in

**EDIT**

I added IMAP account as well, but no email coming from it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't integrate, no.

I believe that it will be the default for `mailto:` links, e.g. mailto:timh@hitchins.tk (it doesn't work here, but if you click on a link like that it will open in the default mail app).

The web-app is simply Gmail in browser. If you want your emails integrated, you need a IMAP account on thunderbird, or some other email reader.

Comment: Do you know why the stopped supporting them? Is it a bug or they discontinued support?

Comment: Umm that's never happened. I think you're thinking of adding your account on Thunderbird or similar. The web app is, literally opening Gmail in a browser with no controls.

Comment: I got that as I can see it in action. When I click on it, it opens the web app in the browser with no control. But on screenshots I saw that their webapps integrate into dash, They can search emails and number of email will appear in the top bar (after you click on the envelope icon). Do you have this on your machine?

Comment: I think that means they have set up an IMAP account as well.

Comment: I did that as well. Check my edited question. I added a snapshot. As you see, I have thunderbird imap set.

Comment: That is now a separate question - that thunderbird won't download email.

Comment: OK. But Thunderbird does download emails as I have been using it for years. It's only the issue with the indicator.

Comment: Yeah, ask another question :)